# Writing equation in polar coordinates for tangent circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates, tangent-line

> How can I write the equation for this tangent circle?
> [image]

Fundamental circle is $r=3\sin(\theta)$ and I also find the tangent line for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$

And the tangent line to the circle is:

$y=-\sqrt{3}x+\frac{9}{2}$ And that is:

[image]

I wonder how can I write the circle equation in polar coordinates for the circle which center is C. Thanks!

Comment: Also now, I find the cartesian coordinates for the tangent circle: $\left(x-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(y-\frac{6}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{9}{4}$

Comment: What is your objective? I can suggest accordingly.

Comment: As I said in the question, I wonder how to write the equation for tangent circle in polar coordinates. In my comment that I have recently wrote I mentioned that I solved for cartesian coordinates. But I can't find this in polar coordinates.

Comment: you typically parametrize the points on the circle or the entire circle, including points on the inside, depending on the situation. That is why I asked the objective. For example, you can parametrize the points on the circle with center $C$ as $(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \cos \theta, 3 + \frac{3}{2} \sin\theta), 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. Here $\theta$ is measured from the center of the circle.

Comment: Don't understand waht you mean by, can you explain more explicitly?

Comment: If you measure the radius and angle from the origin, you replace $x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta$ in the equation $(x- 3 \sqrt3 / 2 )^2 + (y- 3)^2 = 9/4$ but as you can see, it is not easy to resolve for $r$. So a circle in 2D whose center does not lie on any of the coordinate axes is typically parametrized as I mentioned above. Pick different values of $\theta$ and you can see that the parametrization represents points on the circle.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much I undestand!